# What is a good naming convention for Interface Adapters, Use Cases / Interactors, Entities?

Tags: naming, naming-standards, swift-language, clean-architecture

I'm using MVVM + Clean Architecture in my app. And I sometimes don't have any idea if my namings are good enough for each Interface Adapters, Use Cases / Interactors, Entities. For View Models, it's pretty simple. I can just use xxxViewModel as the name. But what about those before? FYI this is my usual namings:

1. Interface Adapters: I use xxxService for the interface / protocol and for the implementation I use xxxAdapter. And for the prefix, I usually use the bounded context. For example I use AuthenticationApiService / Adapter for the Authentication context API calls, AuthorizationApiService / Adapter for the Authorization context API calls, AppointmentApiService / Adapter for Appointment context API calls, StripeService / Adapter for the Stripe framework, GoogePlacesService / Adapter for Google Places, etc.
2. Interactors / Use Cases: Since I injected the function instead of the class, I just use the intention of what I want to do as the class name. Eg:

```
    class SignIn {
        let authenticationApi: AuthenticationApiService
        init(authenticationApi: AuthenticationApiService) {
            self.authenticationApi
        }
    
        // This func will be injected to the view model as the dependency instead of the whole class
        func dataTask(username: String, password: String) -> Observable<UserEntity> {
            authenticationApi.signIn(username: String, password: String)
                .map { decodeToUser(response: $0) }
        }
    
    }
```

But some of the interactors are grouped together into a big class if there are too many that should belong to a single classification. Like Appointment context interactors (basically a class with the whole CRUD operations in it). For this kind of interactors, I am usually unsure how to name them. For the Appointment one, for example, I just name it AppoinmentHandlerProtocol and AppointmentHandler classes for the protocol and implementation.

3. Entities: I just use the naming of xxxEntity like UserEntity, AppointmentEntity, CreditCardEntity, etc. Kind of straight forward although I don't know if this is correct or not. Heck, I don't even know whether they are truly entities or just some POJOs or DTOs. Because I classified all of them as Entities (as in Clean Architecture's definition of entity). Although it's not really a Plain Old Object because I at least have to implement Equatable to make the testings easier.
4. ViewModels: For these classes, I just use the naming like xxxViewModel based on the corresponding Views.

I know that this question is not really an objective one and it's a matter of preference. But I only want to get lots of feedbacks for this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The example of the code can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/brA83jNy

Answer (score 1):

Class and method names are supposed to be abstractions that conceal implementation details, not set them in stone. When you let implementation details leak into a name you make it very hard to change that implementation.

Worse you start to brainwash those who come later into thinking this pattern you've enshrined is the only way to solve the problem and must be followed rigorously regardless of any practical considerations.

Does that mean names can only come from the domain? No. Names have many audiences but most significantly the code that knows those names. The names should not reveal to that code things that code should not know.

This isn't about Object Orientation, Functional Programming, or Procedural. This is about abstraction hiding details so any one idea lives in a small place making that idea easy to change.

So when you say things like:

> Heck, I don't even know whether they are truly entities or just some POJOs or DTOs

Just don't tell us with a name. That's not something most things working with that object need to know. Done that way if you decide you need to change what it is you don't have to refactor the name everywhere it appears.

Of course this creates a new problem. You now have more classes then you have names. Does that mean you need to eliminate classes? No. Just understand what's driving you here isn't that there is some perfect naming convention that is required by the pattern.

When authors show you a pattern with example names they're often butchering the names to make them into things most book readers will understand. Not necessarily setting a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal to question your naming standards. I don't think it matters much tbh, but since you are asking:

Generally speaking including the type in the name, sometimes called Hungarian Notation is usually considered bad.

So, xxxService, xxxEntity, xxxAdapter are code smells to me. If you need to call the User UserEntity, how many different UserXxx classes do you have!

An Exception to the rule would be xxxViewModel which seems to have been adopted in many cases exactly because you need that extra class with the same properties as User plus a few extras for MVVM or MVC patterns.

`AuthenticationApiService` is particularly bad, with both Api and Service, presumably you have an AuthenticationApi and this is the service it uses? you don't give your full structure but how about making more use of namespaces

myCompany.Authentication <-- business logic class

myCompany.Authentication.Models.xxx <-- various data objects exposed by the service

myCompany.Api.Authentication <-- deployment package with hosted authentication logic

myCompany.Api.Authentication.Client <-- package/class used to connect to the Api

In addition make more use of internal or private classes to limit possible name collisions

Comment: About namespaces, I'm afraid Swift doesn't have it, unfortunately. And also, if you use namespaces, it will evolve to a train wreck / long message chaining code smell pretty fast, IMHO.

I do agree that including the type is considered bad. Say, consider this example:
If you want to make some classes for Authentication context like so: one Interface Adapter class to handle communication with the API, one Interactor to handle calling the Interface Adapter and convert the response JSON to either a DTO or Entity to be consumed by the the View Model, how will you name them?

Comment: I would bundle all of those classes in a single client class which returned full objects. User, Order etc. If there was enough code to require sub objects they would be internal to the client assembly or private to the class so they could just be 'TheAdaptor' 'TheInteractor' etc

Comment: Won't that break Single Responsibility Principle?

Comment: shouldnt do, add more code to your example so we can see what you are doing with all these classes

Comment: Well, the whole code will be too big for the comment section (even though it is only one authentication bounded context). So I put it in pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/brA83jNy

Comment: I meant edit your question, but actually that dosent look too bad. I think the convention is to give your interfaces the base name 'Authenticator' the implementation obvs needs something appended 'Client'? and you can skip a bunch of classes by having them do the mapping internally and  return 'User' rather than ResponseModel or Entity. Mappers and other helper classes can be then made private to the 'Client' as they are fully encapsulated

Comment: I am following the Clean Architecture. In Clean Architecture, the Interface-Adapter / Gateway layer's job is to communicate with external dependencies (the API) and will map the data into Response Models. Then there is the Interactor / Use Case layer that will do the logic (in this case mapping the Response Model into an Entity, mapping the Error Response to Error Entity, storing the access token into a repository, etc). So, each layer will not be coupled and can be tested separately. Also if the spec of the API changed, it won't affect the app since the app only knows about the Entity.

Comment: stop doing that it doesn't work and you end up with lots of needless classes

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: If your objection to my solution is that it cant be right because it doesn't fit some other pattern, then it begs the question as to whether that other pattern is good advice. Your code works either way, don't add extra bits you don't need

Comment: No, I was just wondering why you think it won't work. I have worked for 2 years on a company that uses Clean Architecture for most of their products. And being a company that practice XP, they are very rigorous about it. I've got first hand experience where it does work and can compare the benefit of it because I have actually worked on an old product of theirs that doesn't have a good architecture or design. With CA, you can have a pretty clear Separation of Concern, the modules are isolated from one another so they can be tested better, they are more maintainable, extensible and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects (and public methods) should *always* be named after some concept from your requirements.

It specifically doesn't matter what architecture or design pattern you decided to use. Your code becomes more readable (and maintainable) the more you reflect the requirements and concentrate on the business value delivered, instead of technical details.

Services, Entities, Interactors, ViewModels, Adapters are all technical words. **They have absolutely no place in object or method names.** At all.

Comment: Obvious caveat to the first paragraph: helper methods.

Comment: @Flater If you mean helper methods as in private methods in the object to make code more readable, that's why I've said *public* methods. If you mean public shared "utility" methods, then I disagree. Those shouldn't exist either, so the first paragraph still applies.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: Requirements do not spell out specific implementations. That would reduce the field of development to mere translation. Logic/classes can be created to facilitate a certain implementation/pattern/algorithm, without it needing to be _directly_ responsible for the sofware's requirements.

Comment: Sure, we do have technology and patterns and such. Those are literally the implementation. I.e. the code *inside* the methods. As such they are hidden / "invisible". The public signatures of methods, names of classes, i.e. the visible stuff, *are* in fact a summary / translation of the requirements. The more knowledge this translation reveals, the more readable your software becomes. Every class, interface or public method signature not directly covering some requirement is a waste of the reader's and the compiler's time.

Comment: "Services, Entities, Interactors, ViewModels, Adapters are all technical words. They have absolutely no place in object or method names. At all." If that is the case, what about View and ViewController in UIKit?

Comment: @BawenangRukmokoPardianPutra I don't know UIKit specifically, but if your domain *is* UI technology, then of course you may use those words. A library for MVC could conceivably use the words Model, View and Controller. But an application whose purpose is not technology, technology-related words are off-limits.

Comment: helper methods/classes? burn them with fire

Comment: @RobertBräutigam So I've re-read Uncle Bob's Clean Code again and there's this quote: "Remember that the people who read your code will be programmers. So go ahead and use computer science (CS) terms, algorithm names, pattern names, math terms, and so forth. It is not wise to draw every name from the problem domain because we don’t want our coworkers to have to run back and forth to the customer asking what every name means when they already know the concept by a different name." That's a very different approach than yours that says these kinds of technical words don't have any place at all.

Comment: @BawenangRukmokoPardianPutra Seems that way. Then again, I do not agree with Uncle Bob on a lot of other things too. Most recent example is [Clean Architecture](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/a-detailed-analysis-of-the-clean-architecture-from-an-object-oriented-perspective/)

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I see. I read your article above. Interesting PoV. But is always using object-oriented the right thing to do? For me, I will use either OO, procedural or functional depending on the use case at hand. If I want performance and will use DOD, I'll use procedural. If I want clarity and simplicity first I'll do functional, and only when the functions can be grouped together, then I'll refactor them into interfaces+classes and use OO instead. So you will find all of those paradigms in my code. And also, as you can see in my original question, I am using Clean Architecture.

Comment: @BawenangRukmokoPardianPutra Sure, there is always some trade-off I guess. However, I would really have to struggle to find a valid use-case for CA, regardless of paradigm. Also, I don't see how you could mix FP with anything else. As soon as you have side-effects *anywhere*, your FP code becomes effectively useless. Again, a function or lambda-expression here and there might work, but that is not FP.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I don't use only FP in all of my code. What I meant was I use higher-order functions a lot (as the default, even). I don't use interface/protocol as the dependency but instead, I just use the closure. This way, I can inject it only with the needed function instead of the whole class (you don't need the whole forest if you just want a banana). I always try to avoid side effects by only throwing around immutable data and not sharing the states of the objects. Even when there were some side effects, they all have their own unit tests so they are fully tested.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam Anyway, just an idea, considering that it is already 3 years since that article of yours, maybe you can revisit Clean Architecture? There are already plenty of people who use it nowadays.